# Can I redirect to the newest file in directory using .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to create .htaccess rule for situation like below:

- I have a link to file: http://something.com/images/some/image_001.png
- If this file doesn't exists I want to redirect to the newest file in /images/some directory

Is something like this possible using .htaccess? I know that I can check if file exists with RewriteCond, but don't know if it is possible to redirect to the newest file.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a pure mod_rewrite solution for this. The closest thing may be using a `RewriteMap` to point to a script that always returns the newest file in `/images/some`. A simple script like this will always output the latest file in `/images/some` no matter the input:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read in
do
    find /path/to/images/some/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec ls -t1 {} + | head -1 | sed -e 's|/path/to/images/some/||g'
done
```

And if you setup the map in the server or vhost config (maps can't be declared in htaccess):

```
RewriteMap latest prg:/path/to/script.sh
```

And you can invoke it like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?images/some/(.*)$ /images/some/${latest:$1} [L,R=301]
```

Of course, this isn't very efficient, and you're better off just writing a php routing script and direct everything to that instead of a map.

Comment: Hi, can you explain why php will be faster than this?

Comment: @AdrianSerafin I don't know which would be faster, but a php script could be more powerful, maybe rely on some type of cache, more configurable, etc. The `prg` map has the script running all the time, which is why you need to have an infinite loop, otherwise it will only work the first time because the script exits.